# How to write select using two ids combination in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables and the first two columns of these two tables are identical for example:
Table_1 has SSN column and membershipId column
Table_2 also has SSN and membershipId column. They're identical as far as their datatypes but they may have slightly different content. Table_1 may have SSN and membershipId combination that are not already in Table_2.

I need to select records from table_1 where the combination of SSNs and membershipIds are NOT already in table_2. How to write this select statement? I'm using Oracle 11g

so if table_1 has record with SSN = 111-123-2345 and membershipId = 00001234
This record can NOT exist in table-2.

Comment: You're not really using SSN as a key column like this are you? There's some serious data protection issues with that.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility would be:

```
select * 
from Table_1 t1
where not exists 
  (
   select null
   from Table_2 t2
   where t2.SSN = t1.SSN 
     and t2.membershipId = t1.membershipId 
  )
```

In Oracle you could also directly use "NOT IN" ...

Comment: Thank you for the code examples. This is easier for me to understand even though it's longer than the minus statement. Using the minus confused me a little because table_1 has less records than table_2. It may not be a problem because I got the exact same result but language wise it is easier for me to understand using not exist. Thank you again for everyone who have been kind in helping my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You could use MINUS

```
   SELECT SSN, membershipids
   FROM table_1
   MINUS
   SELECT SSN, membershipids
   FROM table_2
```

Example of its use http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/minus.php

Comment: You'd get a redundant distinct sort on the table_1 values, so the NOT EXISTS might be more appropriate here.